# Regarding graphics scripts, and live wallpapers

Tags: android, graphics, live-wallpaper, ram

I have came upon a guide where it teaches how to use a custom graphics script to render alot of particles for a live wallpaper,

my question is, if i have a lot of large bitmaps(images) want to laydown on top of each other to sort of layers, where i have background image, a foreground image and some other images in between which move - than i know it will take a lot of ram for he phone, which is bad - will using a scripts in a way will make it work with less ram?

and in general how scripts help me in rendering graphics in other uses such as games? and so on..

and any links for tutroials about scripts will also be useful :)

Thanks